# How to remove the captions of navigation elements when you click on the Android Studio navigation element for a long time

Tags: android

How can I remove the signatures of the elements in the bottomnavigation, when you press the navigation element for a long time, the name of the fragment will be written above it, how can I remove it? Thank you in advance for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do it override the long click with:

```
bottomNav.setOnLongClickListener {
            true
 }
```